# Maybe functor with results accumulation

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'd like to implement something like a functor for `Option` which accumulates successful results.

It should behave like this (scala-like code below):

```
Some(1).map(_ + 1) # => Some[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))
Some(1).map(_ + 1).map(_ * 3) # => Some[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,2,6))
Some(1).map(_ => None) # Option[None.type] = Some(None)
```

I **do** understand this is not a proper functor because it does not preserve identity:

`Some(42).map(identity) # => Some[(Int, Int]) = Some((42, 42))`

To add some context, I thought it would be useful when there is a chain of maps:

```
val result = Some(42).map(compute_second_value).map(compute_third_value)
```

and a pattern matching on result which depends not only on `result` final value:

```
result match {
  case Some(value) => do_something_with_all_results(result._1, result._2, result._3)
  case None => ...
}
```

So I'm looking for a well-known solution / approach / theoretical term that is related to desired behaviour

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scala, but would the *applicative functor* for `Option` do what you'd like? Let me know if you can use a Haskell or F# answer.

Comment: @MarkSeemann could you please provide an MRE with haskell? That would be very helpful!

Comment: Looking at [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634484/126014), if you're okay with the return values being lists instead of tuples (which completely changes the problem) then a Haskell solution would look much like that answer. It's getting late here, but if you still want to see a Haskell version of that, let me know, and I'll see what I can do tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, seems like that solution would work -- lists are appropriate in my particular case, no need for haskell snippet. Thanks you! @MarkSeemann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it in a "general" way with a `foldLeft` in Scala and working on a sequence rather than a tuple:

```scala
val ops: Seq[Int => Int] = Seq(computeSecondValue, computeThirdValue)

ops.foldLeft(Seq(1)) { case (acc, op) =>
  acc :+ op(acc.last)
}
// Seq[Int]
// Seq(1, computeSecondValue(1), computeThirdValue(computeSecondValue(1)))
```

Or in a less general approach and keeping tuples:

```scala
for {
  first <- Some(1)
  second = computeSecondValue(first)
  third = computeThirdValue(second)
} yield (first, second, third)
// Option[Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]]
```

*In both cases, I didn't manage the `flatMap` case if operations return an `Option` but this can be implemented relatively easily by the reader.*

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about using simple `foldLeft`. However, could this implementation detail be encoded via `map` or similar method?

Comment: @vetements A *fold* is a more general function than *map*. For lists, you can implement *map* with *fold*, but not the other way around, *map* being more specialized.

Comment: Got it, thanks @MarkSeemann